# mix blending mode not working on white image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply this code find online to change the image color according to the user selection. here is the code I find https://codepen.io/smashtheshell/pen/wvzwMLO

using img and mix blend mode apply the color on image like by the user

```css
:root {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  box-sizing: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.product img {
  max-width: 100%;
  min-width: 20rem;
}
.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
  background-color: hsl(30, 50%, 75%);
}
.product::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: hsl(30, 50%, 75%);
  /* opacity: 0.5; */
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
}

.product-nav {
  position: relative;
}
.product-nav label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5vmin;
  height: 5vmin;
  background-color: hsl(30, 50%, 75%);
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0.5em #fff, 0.5em 0.5em 1em -0.15em rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  transition: 200ms all ease-in-out;
}

.product-nav label + label {
  margin-left: 2.5em;
}

.product-nav label:nth-of-type(1),
#color-1:checked ~ .product::after {
  background-color: hsl(30, 50%, 75%);
}
.product-nav label:nth-of-type(2),
#color-2:checked ~ .product::after {
  background-color: hsl(120, 50%, 75%);
}
.product-nav label:nth-of-type(3),
#color-3:checked ~ .product::after {
  background-color: hsl(210, 50%, 75%);
}
.product-nav label:nth-of-type(4),
#color-4:checked ~ .product::after {
  background-color: hsl(300, 50%, 75%);
}

#color-1:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(1),
#color-2:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(2),
#color-3:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(3),
#color-4:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(4) {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

#color-1:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: hsl(30, 70%, 45%);
}
#color-2:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: hsl(120, 70%, 45%);
}
#color-3:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: hsl(210, 70%, 45%);
}
#color-4:checked ~ .product-nav > label:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: hsl(300, 70%, 45%);
}
```

```html
    <section class="container">
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color-1" checked hidden>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color-2" hidden>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color-3" hidden>
        <input type="radio" name="color" id="color-4" hidden>

        <div class="product">
            <img src="http://pngimg.com/uploads/vans/vans_PNG24.png" alt="Product">
        </div>

        <div class="product-nav">
            <label for="color-1"></label>
            <label for="color-2"></label>
            <label for="color-3"></label>
            <label for="color-4"></label>
        </div>

    </section>
```

But when try to apply on image with white color it is not working. any solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't figured this out yourself by now:

Changing the **hue** (the 'color tone' in color wheel degrees) of a color does not change its *saturation* nor its *lightness*. Any grayscale image has pixels with `saturation: 0%`, so after a *hue* change you are still left with a grayscale image. This is true for any shade of gray between *black* and *white* (the *lightness* parameter). **Despite** the fact that you are mixing it with a saturated color, only the *hue* of that color is transfered.

The quick solution is using `mix-blend-mode: color-burn`, but this has the side effect that colors will get deeper contrast, whcih will need to be corrected. Probably different contrast values per color transfered.

To add insult to injury, the following can be *very* confusing at first:

- **linear colors**: when using the CSS `hsl(..)` function for a color, only changing the *hue* will yield that specific *color tone* from the color wheel. E.g. `hsl(0, 100%, 50%)`, HTML 'red', changed to its complementary color `hsl(180, 100%, 50%)` yields HTML 'cyan'. We programmers like that, 0 + 180 = 180 = 'cyan'. Straightforward logic, however...
- **perceptive colors** `mix-blend-mode` and `filter: hue-rotate(..)` use internal (internationally accepted) color conversion tables to create colors that change the *color tone*, but also the 'feeling' of a color. E.g. the complementary color of above 'red' becomes a 'darker green', which has a *saturation* and *lightness* that 'feel' the same as those of 'red'. For me as a programmer it means `1 + 1 = 2`, but it feels like `1`. Which just does not compute... (don't try to figure out the mathematical logic, browser literally use hardcoded arrays for the *perceptive* color conversion).

So, if you think you are blending a 'red' toned image with 'cyan', don't be surprised when it turns out to be 'some shade of green'.

When you feel really confident: [Mozilla source: gfx/src/FilterSupport.cpp](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/tip/gfx/src/FilterSupport.cpp), check the various *filter matrix* functions. Used by `SVG filters`, `blend-mode` and `filter`...